# PostGIS (2.0?) - Native Versioning of the Datastore

Tags: data, cartography, spatial-database, editing, metadata

I recently have been surprised to see there are not too many solutions at all discussing the best methods of versioning datastores which are made available for editing.

I am looking for a robust, efficient solution which would me to share a bunch of data with registered users and where those users can edit this geodata or associating attributes individually. My requirement though is that I need any and all edits logged so they can be rolled back to any previous state just like a wiki.

More specifically, I am utilizing a tool called CartoDB.com (built on PostGIS 2.0) through which whatever method needs to be compatible.

Very curious to learn any/all information you guys might be able to share in regards to my needs. Thanks - CH

Comment: just for reference about geodata versioning.. http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoGit+approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heard whispers about GeoGit at FOSS4G.  Chris Holmes and others are working on this as a WFS-Versioning replacement, of sorts.  Don't know how far along the project is, or how it would tie in with spatial databases like PostGIS... .

http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/GeoGit+approach

Answer (score 0):

Smallworld has a versioned object oriented database, I mean , we need it the database to be versioned, with merge, post and conflict resolution feature.

Answer (score -2):

Probably the best commercial available version-managed database is [Smallword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallworld), leader in utility & telco market.

Comment: seems to work only with Oracle - according to the wiki page linked